# Windows Azure: Mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am using VS 2012, Azure v1.8, Windows 8.1
**Update**: Updated Azure to 2.5, but still error.

Using VS2012 > Server Explorer > Windows Azure Compute > Add Deployment Environment, I have added subscription via publish settings file.

Now when I want to choose the deployment environment, I am getting below error.

> Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Unable to load services for the given credentials. An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://management.core.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxx/services/hostedservices.
>
> This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case.
>
> This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

[image]

I even check tried the solution of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560700/windows-azure-authentication-error-when-trying-to-create-credentials)

**Note**: I have already deployed applications on my azure account couple of months back, now I want to updated them.

> **Update1**: Upgraded Azure to version 2.5

I update Azure version to 2.5, now when I select ....  Server Explorer > Azure > Manage Subscriptions, getting error as

***An error occurred during the sign in process: service_returned_error: Serviced returned error. Check InnerException for more details***

[image]

> **Update2** 2015-03-10: Used Fiddler

After updating to Azure 2.5, was unable to connect to Azure from VS 2012.

I started fiddler
 - Enabled decrypt https.
 - Added the required ClientCertificate.cer to C:\Users\user1\Documents\Fiddler2

Now from VS 2012, can connect to Azure using user id and password.

When publishing to Azure, was able to publish and application worked, but it did not finish the complete process 100%.

Now if I stop fiddler and then again ...  I am getting same error.

Comment: Does this help? http://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-operational-insights/suggestions/6519323-having-an-issue-connecting-to-advisor-service-from

Comment: I tried by adding the registry setting with value 0 and 1, still same error.
Looks like setting is related to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with AnkhSvn-2.5.12266.

Once I removed it, I was able to connect to Azure.

Due to AnkhSvn-2.5.12266 VS 2012 was using SSL V3.0 and to prevent the POODLE attack, Azure rejects all request, which uses SSL 3.0 Protocol.

Comment: Upgraded AnkhSvn to **2.5.12582** and SVN to **1.8.10**, after upgraded I can connect Azure also.